# Manga about a character who gets lost in the woods, wanders around and finds this small shack with a young male hermit

Tags: identification-request, manga

I remember reading a few chapters of a Japanese manga about 3 years ago, but my memory of it is very hazy. The story was not current and had been in production for several years already. If I had to guess, it started serialization around 2010 or earlier, but the artstyle implies 2000s.

There's a character who gets lost in the woods, wanders around and finds this small shack with a young male hermit living there. The "hermit" had light hair, I think. The inside of the shack was mostly filled with bookshelves. The two characters had long-winded conversations about something fantastic or philosophical.

I know this isn't much to go on, but I'd really like to read it.

Comment: Where did you acquire the manga from? What language was it in? What about the art style implies 2010s?